# How do I exclude the last line of user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm trying to get user inputs to write a file at run time. But it writes the delimiter (`-99`) also. Is there any simpler code rather than this one without including delimiter?

In the past, I've tried on Python 3 in Jupyter lab.

```
lines=input("Enter the contents:")
while(lines!="-99"):
    lines=input()
    file.write(lines)
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

I expect the output of user contents upto `-99` (that is, excluding `-99`), but the actual output is user contents with `-99`.

**Sample Output**

```
Enter the contents:
 Hi
 Hello
 Welcome to python lab
-99
```

In my output file:

```
 Hi
 Hello
 Welcome to python lab
-99
```

Comment: What is your input and the expected output that should save to file? Add it to the question

Comment: Input is anything which is entered by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply rewrite the `while` loop so that the break happens before the write to the file.

```
print("Enter the contents:")
with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    while True:
        line = input()
        if line == "-99":
            break
        print(line, file=file)
```

I made some other improvements to the code.

#### To simplify the loop

You could use `fileinput`:

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    if line == "-99":
        break
    print(line, file=file)
```

In Python 3.8, you'll be able to use the walrus operator:

```
while (line := input()) != "-99":
    print(line, file=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
print("Enter the contents: ")
with open(file_name, "a") as file:
    while True:
        data = input()
        if data == '-99':
            break
        else:
            file.write(data+'\n')
```

By this, `-99` won't store in your file.

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper OP doesn't want to store `-99` to file. Why should `write` to file before `break`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't write -99, but does terminate on it:

```
filename= 'test.out' 
def contents(): 
  return input ("Enter the Contents: ") 
getcontents=contents() 
with open (filename, 'w') as f: 
   while getcontents != '-99': 
      f.write(getcontents + "\n") 
      getcontents=contents()
```

Comment: if you format it correctly, you don't need to break